# Access: ListBox.Column Property Object required

Tags: ms-access, vba

According to [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834793.aspx) `.Column(1, 0)` Should work for Access Form ListBoxes but I am getting an objext required error for `.Column(1, 0) = "Name"` Here is the full line of code.

```
With Me.ListBox_Status
.AddItem ("User")
.AddItem "VICI Launcher" '4
.AddItem (Command_Mx.Caption) '0
.AddItem (Command_Fm.Caption) '1
.AddItem (Command_Anal.Caption) '2
.AddItem "DB Backup" '5
.Column(1, 0) = "Name'"
'Call UserIn
WasteTime (1)
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use the Column property to refer to a specific column, or column and row combination, in a multiple-column combo box or list box.
>   **Read-only Variant**.

The problem is that the `.Column()` property is read-only. You can't use it to set a "cell" in the listbox.
It is only used to read values from it.

But the error message is quite strange and misleading. I can't really imagine what Access is trying to do here.

Comment: So `AddItem` method is the only way to fill more than one column?

Comment: Yes, I think it is not possible to edit values, only by `.RemoveItem` and `.AddItem`. My listboxes usually have a query as rowsource, there you can simply do `myListBox.Requery`. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_other/help-edit-existing-values-in-a-listbox-in-access/e638c61b-14e3-44bf-83ea-970e87d8b528